# How to connect postgresql database without using sudo

Tags: sudo, postgresql

I need to create a postgres database on a linux server. However, I don't have admin privileges and cannot use sudo. How to install postgres and create a database without using sudo. I looked at several tutorials but all includes the use of sudo.

Comment: Use PostgreSQL in a Docker container? If you're allowed to run these as your user, that is.

Comment: Without sudoer rights, you can't actually install or initialize a PostgreSQL server on the system that you are using. As suggested, you can acquire a Podman or Docker container with PostgreSQL but you'd need to have rootless Podman or Docker enabled on the system.

Comment: There are multiple how-to's on installing postgresql without root. For example, [on Ubuntu](https://gist.github.com/yunpengn/832aceac6998e2f894e5780229920cb5) or [using pip](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/install-a-local-non-root-postgresql-server-with-python-pip-2291/). You will not be able to have the daemon listen on port 5432 but that likely is not a problem on a non-production instance.

Comment: @doneal24 Sure, but that is compiling it from the source code, not installing it as the latter requires a package manager to install the packages for PostgreSQL which requires sudoer rights which aren't available. For compilation, the question is, are the compilation tools the needed libraries and headers available on the system? If they are, then one can proceed with that method provided that the user has modify access to available space. If not, then it can't be done. To go any further, more information regarding that and the OS and release are needed.

Comment: @doneal24, 5432 is not privileged port and there is no problem ordinary user to run daemon, which listen to this port.

Comment: @NasirRiley The OP said he did not have root/sudo rights, Never mentioned if compilation tools were available so I did not require that in my answer. Without looking further into it, I don't know if the `pip` solution will work without a development environment. So for a complete answer, we need to know if any of `gcc`, `python`, `docker`, `singularity`, `wget`, `curl`, etc. are available along with if the OP has enough disk space allocated under his quota to install the binaries and the database data. Installing into a user-directory does not require either a package manager or sudo rights.

Comment: @RomeoNinov You are correct. I was assuming the worst case scenario where the server already has a postgresql instance running on the default port.

Comment: @doneal24, do not assume anything, ask OP

Comment: @NasirRiley To put it more succinctly, `/home/foo/bin/pgsql` works just as well as `/usr/bin/pgsql` as long as you have the tools to download and compile the binary. You could likely download the deb/rpm, extract the contents into your home directory, and still be able to run a stand-alone instance without any other tools (unless the [sysadmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastard_Operator_From_Hell) took precautions  to keep you from doing this.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I agree that we need to ask the OP some questions but where does it stop? Do you have internet access to repositories? Are you allowed to download tar.gz or wheel files? Do you have enough disk quota for the downloads? Is a current and sufficient python environment installed? Is a GCC development installed? Does the local firewall block everything other than the officially-sanctioned services on either the allowed network ports, localhost, or Unix sockets? How many of these questions should  we present to a new user?

Comment: @doneal24 It will stop when there is adequate information to determine what can be done. The question was how does one install it. That would require a package manager which can't be used without sudoer rights. Running it in a container has requirements whether using Podman or Singularity that have already been mentioned as does compiling it from source. using Python, or any other method.

Comment: @doneal24 Aslo, one cannot "install" it into a user directory. That would require compilation tools of which the presence isn't known. In fact, no one knows if any of those things are available on the system or whether or not the person knows how to use them. The page to which you linked included compilation tools. Everything else that you mentioned also has requirements. That's what RomeoNinov was getting at when stating not to assume anything. You've no idea.

Comment: @NasirRiley If an "install" requires a package manager, what does the common command `make install` actually do? Does breaking an rpm package out using `rpm2cpio` and then copying the files actually meet that OP's purpose even it it is not an "install". If we cannot assume *anything*, then the huge majority of questions on U&L should be closed under "needs details or clarity". As I alluded to in an earlier comment, is there a reasonable set of assumptions on what is available to a user? Or do we drop down to saying they are running in a restricted shell with limited or no network ...

Comment: @NasirRiley connectivity and a small disk quota? Before any answer can be proposed we must require confirmation that additional tools are actually available even if those tools are commonly installed with the distribution.

Comment: @NasirRiley To summarize, without knowing what tools are available to the user, should we tell them that it cannot be done without sudo rights unless they have rights to start Docker containers (which essentially give them sudo rights), or should we give instructions on how to install using tools that are often available. I would err on the side of try it this way rather than give up all hope, all ye who enter here. If the standard instructions don't fit their situation, they can come back for further help. Better in my mind than accepting that it cannot be done.

Comment: @doneal24 No one is making the case that it can't be done at all. You are taking it to an extreme as no one has said that. There are ways to do it. The important thing is to find out what is available before providing those ways. It's just as useless to direct someone to do something with no idea of whether or not it's even possible.

Comment: @NasirRiley I apologize. I misunderstood the comment "Without sudoer rights, you can't actually install or initialize a PostgreSQL server".

Comment: @doneal24 No problem. It would have been better to put it this way: "It isn't possible to install PostgreSQL via the package manager and then initialize it without sudoer rights. There are other methods but more information is needed on the system including the OS, release, available tools, and your knowledge of components such as compiling software and running a container before anything can be recommended."

Answer (score 0):

We really need a bit more detail for a full answer but you have a few options.

If the postgresql package is already installed on the system, ask the admins to create a database for you and give you privileges only on it. This is the simplest solution if the database engine is already present. If it is present but the admins don't want to cooperate, you can create your own pg config file pointing to a strictly local instance and run your own copy of the daemon.

Second choice, assuming that a compilation environment is available, is to download the source package and compile it yourself. [postgres.org](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-install.html) has directions on how to do this in a manner that does not require any system privileges.

Distant third choice is to download the .rpm or .deb files from the [postgresql download page)[https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/repos/). You will then need to force the installation of these files to be under your own home directory. For REL-type systems, investigate `rpm -i --relocate`. For Debian/Ubuntu, you might not need to download the .deb files but just use `apt install postgresql-16 -o DPkg::options::="--root=/home/heyula/pgsql"`. You still might need to specify a sources file for the particular repository. In either case, the system's package manager is being used for the installation but the system database of installed packages is not updated.

You might also be able to find a pre-built postgresql tar.gz file that you can just untar. These are rare but do exist. I would avoid this option unless everything else fails.

In any of these cases it is unlikely that you will be able to listen on port 5432 without having sudo privileges unless the firewall rules have been relaxed.  Except for the listening port, you do not need sudo rights or the ability to run containers to set up your own postgresql instance.